# Rails filtering with scopes not returning results from multiple paramters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, filtering, api-design

I have the following scope defined in the model:

```
  scope :filter_by_language, -> (language) { where( languages: {language_name: language}) }
```

and in the controller I use

```
@things= @things.filter_by_language(params[:language]).includes(:language) if params[:language].present?
```

and this works for a single query like so:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/things?language=French
```

but my research suggests that I should be able to return results from multiple languages by using & in the get request to return all the matching results, so this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/things?language=French&language=English
```

but I only the results from the last parameter, so in this case only English results, not English and French.

Can anyone point me in the direction I am going wrong? many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to send those non-escalar parameters using square brackets, like:

```
?language[]=French&language[]=English
```

Documentation: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters